# why does this text overlaps in the sidebar?

Tags: css, sidebar

I've been trying, without success, to remove to sliding of the text:  "ggplot+background+grid+colour"

From the left sidebar [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/)

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost missed it, looks fine in Opera. :)

Basically these words are not treated as words, but as one giant word. And browsers (well, except Opera) have trouble interpreting how to wrap it.

Not sure how to achieve nice wrapping, but quick fix would be adding CSS rule `overflow: hidden;` to `.side-widget ul{}`